Example: if $\overline{\varphi}: M/IM \to N/IN$ is injective, $\varphi:M \to N$ need not be injective
Let $I$ be an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of a (commutative, unital) ring $R$. Let $M$ be an $R$- module, $N$ a finitely generated $R$-module and $\varphi:M \to N $ a homomorphism of $R$-modules. Show that if the induced homomorphism $ \overline{\varphi}: M/IM → N/IN $ is injective, then $\varphi$
does not have to be injective.
This question is related to excercise 2.10 of Atiyah and MacDonald’s Introduction to Commutative Algebra. Only there $\overline{\varphi}$ surjective does imply $\varphi$ surjective.
I don't really know how to get started so any help is appreciated.

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.
